# Attachment gets duplicated in apple mail client when mail sent through the gmail api php code

Tags: php, gmail-api, apple-mail

I am using the Gmail Api code in php to send mails to clients. The mail contains multiple attachments and all works good except for the clients who are using the apple mail app. They see the duplicated attachments. That is if the mail has 4 different attachments, all they see in apple mail app is 4 same duplicated attachments. Please see my code below.

```
$objGMail = new Google_Service_Gmail($this->googleauth->client);
$strRawMessage = "";
$boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);
$subjectCharset = $charset = 'utf-8';

$strRawMessage .= 'To: ' .$toEmailsName . " <" . $ToEmail . ">" . "\r\n"; 
$strRawMessage .= 'Cc: ' .$ccEmailsName . " <" . $CcEmail . ">" . "\r\n";  
$strRawMessage .= 'Bcc: ' .$BccEmailsName . " <" . $BccEmail . ">" . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'From: '.$fromName . " <" . $fromEmail . ">" . "\r\n";   
$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?' . $subjectCharset . '?B?' . base64_encode($EmailSubject) . "?=\r\n";         
$strRawMessage .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 

//Attachments
if (isset($post['UploadedFileName'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($post['UploadedFileName']); $i++) {
        if ($post['UploadedFileName'][$i] <> "") {                                                                 
            $filePath = './attachments/' . $post['UploadedFileName'][$i];
            $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);                   
            $fileName = $post['UploadedFileName'][$i];                  
            $fileData = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)), 76, "\n") . "\r\n";       

            $strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";                                                                                                  
            $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
            $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: '. $mimeType .'; name="'. $fileName .'";' . "\r\n";            
            $strRawMessage .= 'Content-ID: <' . $fromEmail . '>' . "\r\n";            
            $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Description: ' . $fileName . ';' . "\r\n";
            $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"; size=' . filesize($filePath). ';' . "\r\n";
            $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";               
            $strRawMessage .=  $fileData;               
            $strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";                                                                                                 
        }
    }
}

$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= $EmailBody . "\r\n";
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
$objSentMsg = $objGMail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you use the same `Content-ID` for all the attachments. Try giving them unique IDs.

Comment: Or just leave out that header if you're not referencing the attachments from the body of the email.

Comment: @Barmar, That worked !!.. Thanks a lot Barmar.. Much appreciated